# Звездочка в MATCH AGAINST

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

Есть строка, например, `ИмяТовара 3*1,5`

Из документации прочитал, что * является оператором усечения. Вопрос в том, какая по итогу строка будет отдана на поиск при наличии звездочки ? Та, которая написана выше ? Или с какими то изменениями ? Если с изменениями, можно ли предотвратить эти изменения и оставить строку такой, какая она есть

Comment: Зависит от режима поиска.

Comment: @Akina без указания режимов. Т.е MATCH(title) AGAINST ("ИмяТовара 3*1,5")

Comment: Не, нормально так... режим есть ВСЕГДА. Вопрос - какой он будет у тебя... Я уж не говорю о том, что неплохо бы указать СУБД - причём включая точную версию.

Comment: @Akina По умолчанию ведь идет IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE. Явно я никакой мод не указываю. 10.3.22-MariaDB

Comment: Плюс stopwords, плюс минимальная длина токена... а служебные символы ищутся вообще только в BOOLEAN MODE, и то не все.

Comment: @Akina Такое чувство, что мы совсем о разных вещах говорим. Без логического режима моя строка в поиске будет выглядеть как `ИмяТовара 3*1,5`, или с какими то отклонениями ?